# depends on a node named 'energy_dbt_model' which was not found

Tags: python, etl, dbt, duckdb

I was trying out to find out how to query my duckdb file. When I run `dbt run --select energy_dbt_model`. I keep getting the error

> Model 'model.transform_dbt.first_model' (models\example\first_model.sql) depends on a node named 'energy_dbt_model' which was not found

this is my schema.yml file

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: energy_dbt_model
    description: this dataset holds the data of the captured solar and wind energy also the price and the datetime this data was captured, this dataset has data for every 15 minuts
    columns:
      - name: id
        description: "The primary key for this table"
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
      - name: date_time
        description: The datetime the data was captured
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
      - name: solar_measured
        description: The amount of solar energy produced in the whole of belgium at the given timestamp
        tests:
          - not_null
      - name: wind_measured
        description: The amount of wind energy produced in Belgium at the given timestamp
        tests:
          - not_null
      - name: solar_price
        description: The calculated price for solar energy at that given timestamp
        tests:
          - not_null
      - name: wind_price
        description: The calculated price for wind energy at that given timestamp
        tests:
          - not_null
```

this is my `first_model.sql` which I am trying to run.

```
SELECT * FROM {{ ref('energy_dbt_model') }}
```

this is my profiles.yml file

```
transform_dbt: # this needs to match the profile in your dbt_project.yml file
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: duckdb
      path: './energy.duckdb'
      extensions:
        - httpfs
        - parquet
```

this is mostly copied from the internet I just changed the path var.

and this is my dbt_project.yml file.

```
# Name your project! Project names should contain only lowercase characters
# and underscores. A good package name should reflect your organization's
# name or the intended use of these models
name: 'transform_dbt'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

# This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.
profile: 'transform_dbt'

# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
# The `model-paths` config, for example, states that models in this project can be
# found in the "models/" directory. You probably won't need to change these!
model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"  # directory which will store compiled SQL files
clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"


# Configuring models
# Full documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configuring-models

# In this example config, we tell dbt to build all models in the example/
# directory as views. These settings can be overridden in the individual model
# files using the `{{ config(...) }}` macro.
models:
  transform_dbt:
    # Config indicated by + and applies to all files under models/example/
    example:
      +materialized: view
```

I'm very new to dbt and it could as well be a very dumb mistake.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, so a question ( a sentence ending in a question mark) should always be included in the body of your post. Don't assume we understand what you want to ask, for me the first thing to come to mind would be "If I rename the files with YAML documents to the extension `.yaml` that has been the officially recommended extension since September 2006, will the error go away?`", but that might not be your question. There is also no "path var", as there are no vars in a YAML doc. You have a key `path` in  with a value is `'./energy.duckdb'` which is a scalar with superfluous quotes.